# Bootstrap - Example Modal Window Not Working?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I cant get the example modal window to work. I think it may be something to do with the way I'm referencing:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Test 123</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're referencing jquery twice... I wonder if that's causing your problems.

Comment: I removed one of them but didn't make a difference. The screen flashes and goes back to normal.

Comment: you're also referencing bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js. Choose one of them!

Comment: delete also duplicated references for boostrap

Comment: I do have 2 for bootstrap.min, but one is js and one is css?

Comment: What is `js/bootstrap.js`?

Comment: Local version which I placed into solution

Comment: Then it seems you're referencing it twice `js/bootstrap.js` and `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js`. Remove one of them.

Comment: FYI your code is working fine of Bootply http://www.bootply.com/rM2HVSUOtz so as noted by others you probably have an issue with how you're loading js